# Regex subsequence matching

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python but code in any language will do as well for this question.

Suppose I have 2 strings.

```
sequence ='abcd'
string = 'axyzbdclkd'
```

In the above example `sequence` is a subsequence of `string`

How can I check if `sequence` is a subsequence of `string` using regex? Also check the examples [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/) for difference in subsequence and subarray and what I mean by subsequence.

The only think I could think of is this but it's far from what I want.

```
import re
c = re.compile('abcd')
c.match('axyzbdclkd')
```

Comment: You already asked this question today...

Comment: Yea but had some other work so wouldn't have been able to respond that's why closed it and asked now as I've got some time on hand :-P..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just allow arbitrary strings in between:

```
c = re.compile('.*a.*b.*c.*d.*')
# .* any character, zero or more times
```

Comment: This will only work if the `sequence` does not contain any special characters.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yea true but I'm having just lowercase characters

Comment: If the pattern grows longer, and the input is big, backtracking will most likely cause a "crash".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The pattern would be max around 20 characters and the string would be around 50-100 characters.. Would it be alright?..

Answer (score 3):

You can, for an arbitrary `sequence` construct a regex like:

```
import re

sequence = 'abcd'
rgx = re.compile('.*'.join(re.escape(x) for x in sequence))
```

which will - for `'abcd'` result in a regex `'a.*b.*c.*d'`. You can then use `re.find(..)`:

```
the_string = 'axyzbdclkd'
if rgx.search(the_string):
    # ... the sequence is a subsequence.
    pass
```

By using `re.escape(..)` you know for sure that for instance `'.'` in the original `sequence` will be translated to `'\.'` and thus not match *any* character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution is as simple as @schwobaseggl claims. Let me show you another sequence from your database: `ab1b2cd`. By using the `abcd` subsequence for pattern matching you can get 2 results: `ab(1b2)cd` and `a(b1)b(2)cd`. So for testing purposes the proposed `^.*a.*b.*c.*d.*$` is ok(ish), but for parsing the `^a(.*)b(.*)cd$` will always be greedy. To get the second result you'll need to make it lazy: `^a(.*?)b(.*)cd$`. So if you need this for parsing, then you should know how many variables are expected and to optimize the regex pattern you need to parse a few example strings and put the gaps with capturing groups only to the positions you really need them. An advanced version of this would inject the pattern of the actual variable instead of `.*`, so for example `^ab(\d\w\d)cd$` or `^a(\w\d)b(\d)cd$` in the second case.